# Can I raise a number to the power of i?

Tags: complex-analysis

I was just wondering if the rules of exponents still applied to imaginary and complex numbers, like if $(2^4)^i=2^{4i}$ or not and if $(4^i)^i=4^{-1}$, etc

Comment: Short version: Yes, but you have to be careful.

Comment: If you write the complex number in polar form $z=re^{i\theta}$ you can see that $(re^{i\theta})^i=re^{i^2\theta}=re^{-\theta}$.

Comment: Why is $r$ not raised to the $i$ in these comments?

Answer (score 2):

I think some of the comments are in error.

If $z = r e^{i \theta}$ with $r$ a positive real
(if $z = 0$, then $z^i = 0$),
$z = r e^{i (\theta + 2 \pi k)}$
for any integer $k$,
so $z^i = r^i e^{i^2 (\theta + 2 \pi k)}
= e^{i \ln r} e^{- (\theta + 2 \pi k)}
= (\cos( \ln r) + i \sin(\ln r)) e^{- (\theta + 2 \pi k)}
$.

The principal value is usually the one with $k = 0$,
but all the other values are possible.

Comment: What about without an equation like re^(iθ)? What about x^i for any x?

Answer (score 1):

The exact same rules apply. A nice example of this is a typical Oxbridge interview question;

$$
What\ is\ i^i\ ?
$$

$$
i^i = {(e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}})} ^ i = e^{i^2\frac{\pi}{2}} = e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}} \approx 0.20788 
$$

Comment: I asked my math teachers this question when I was about 12.  It took some time to get an answer.

Comment: How do you go from i^i to (e^(i*pi/2))^i?